# Strikethrough property

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

How to delete strike out rows in excel sheet using c#?

I have tried this:

```
{
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("D:/Excel.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)app.Sheets["Production_2013"];
    Excel.Range range = ws.get_Range("A5", "T10");
    string clean_string = CleanStrikethroughChars(range);
}

string CleanStrikethroughChars(Excel.Range range) {
    string s = "";
    int char_index = 1;
    int length = range.Cells.Value2.ToString().Length;

    while (char_index < length) {
        if ((bool)range.Cells.get_Characters(char_index, 1).Font.Strikethrough) {
            s += range.Cells.get_Characters(char_index, 1).Text;
            char_index++;
        }
    }
    return s;
```

Comment: Do you want to delete entire rows or characters? Your solution deletes characters, not rows.

Comment: I have to delete entire rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways to determine how to do things using the Excel interops is to create a macro in Excel of the intended operation and then look at the resulting VBA code. That might provide a hint on how to do what is needed.